# How to Return a Caught Error in my Response? (AWS Lambda Node.js 14)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function connected to API Gateway. My function looks basically like this:

```
 exports.handler = async(event)=>{
    try {
        //to do stuff 
    } catch (e) {
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                CaughtException: e,
                req: event
            }),
        }
        return response;
    }
 }
```

When I use the Lambda test Event, I can see the error in the function logs section:
[image]

As you can see, I am trying to send this error as part of my response, but it's just an empty object :(

[image]

How can I access this error?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to look on the code that throw the exception.
I think that there's somethink like a Promise.reject({}), in this case the catch (e) will catch an empty object, like your case.

Answer (score 0):

[This would help](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/handle-errors-in-lambda-integration.html#handle-custom-errors-in-lambda-integration)

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {        
    ...
    // Error caught here:
    var myErrorObj = {
        errorType : "InternalServerError",
        httpStatus : 500,
        requestId : context.awsRequestId,
        trace : {
            "function": "abc()",
            "line": 123,
            "file": "abc.js"
        }
    }
    callback(JSON.stringify(myErrorObj));
};
```